# Emigrate to UK from Argentina

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, argentine-citizens

My Argentinian friend would like to know what to do to live permanently in the UK.

According to gov.uk the coalition government handed over visa responsibility to VFS Global. So is it a case of visiting the website to apply for a working visa or will she have to apply for a job first, be accepted and then ask the company if they have a sponsor licence and then apply for a working visa?

Also whilst working and not leaving the country would permanent residency be granted after 5 years?

Comment: Information about the various working visas that are available is here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/argentina/work/longer_than_six_months Information about the right to reside is here https://www.gov.uk/right-to-reside

Comment: The UK government is entirely responsible for its visas. They do have commercial partners for online processing of applications and data. But the UK government decides, based on the strength of the application, and the preponderance of evidence, who gets a visa and who doesn't. That has always been the case and will always be the case so long as the UK remains a sovereign nation. There are many routes to living permanently in the UK. It really depends on her own dreams and desires, as well as her genuine ability to  qualify via whatever route she may choose to try.

Comment: Does your friend have any possibility of claiming citizenship of an EU country (Italy and Ireland have relatively permissive rules, unless they've changed in the last few years).